# How to parallel read one region of HBase?

Tags: hbase

I want to improve speed scan of client by multiple thread to read one region, but the region has one tuple of start key and end key, How to get some groups of start/end keys that were divided from start/end key of one region?

Answer (score 1):

HBase scan object has a startRow/stopRow property.

If you scan the table with HBase client api, you can try create several scans with different start/end rows and run them in parallel.

Region start/end keys are accessible via HBaseAdmin api. The way you divide your key space depends on your data, you can always use lexicographical splits.